# When I install my app I get a random Notification Android

Tags: java, android

I have no Idea why this is happening but whenever I install my app after I get my DeviceID (For push notifications) I receive a notification that I've never sent.

Can someone help me to figure out what could cause this behaviour?

This is the code of my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
               GcmIntentService.class.getName());
       startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
   }
}
```

And this is my `IntentService`:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("mycode"); //I've edited my code
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("alert");
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, AnimationActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300})
        .setContentTitle(message);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

In order to retrieve my DeviceID I just use:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(AnimationActivity.this);
                regID = instanceID.getToken(("mycode"),GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null); //I've edited my code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the registration id is achieved from google server, GCMBroadcastRecevier class is invoked so it is generating a notification via GCMIntentService. I am sure approach of client side implementation is wrong
For easy and convenient client side implementation of GCM you can refer this link.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging.